# SimpleXML and Element Arrays, Possible Bug?

Tags: php, debugging, simplexml

I'm running PHP 7.0.0Beta3 (I'm compiling RC1 right now. and I have an issue.

```
<?php

    $XML = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <GetExampleResponse xmlns="http://example.net/webservices">
            <GetExampleResult>
                <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
                    <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xs:element name="Table">
                                    <xs:complexType>
                                        <xs:sequence>
                                            <xs:element name="CENTER" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                        </xs:sequence>
                                    </xs:complexType>
                                </xs:element>
                            </xs:choice>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:schema>
                <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
                    <NewDataSet xmlns="">
                        <Table diffgr:id="Table1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
                            <CENTER>POLICE PSAP</CENTER>
                        </Table>
                        <Table diffgr:id="Table2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
                            <CENTER>POLICE PSAP</CENTER>
                        </Table>
                    </NewDataSet>
                </diffgr:diffgram>
            </GetExampleResult>
        </GetExampleResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
XML;

    $XML = new SimpleXMLElement(str_ireplace(['soap:', 'xs:', 'xmlns:', 'msdata:', 'diffgr:'], '', $XML));

    print_r($XML->Body->GetExampleResponse->GetExampleResult->diffgram->NewDataSet);

    print_r($XML->Body->GetExampleResponse->GetExampleResult->diffgram->NewDataSet->Table);

?>
```

The output of that script is this

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [Table] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => Table1
                            [rowOrder] => 0
                        )

                    [CENTER] => POLICE PSAP
                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => Table2
                            [rowOrder] => 1
                        )

                    [CENTER] => POLICE PSAP
                )

        )

)
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [id] => Table1
            [rowOrder] => 0
        )

    [CENTER] => POLICE PSAP
)
```

The only difference between the two print_r lines is that I'm going to down one more level`->Table` but in doing that, I no longer get the array, I only get it's first element.

This is my expected result for the `print_r($XML->Body->GetExampleResponse->GetExampleResult->diffgram->NewDataSet->Table);` call.

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [id] => Table1
                    [rowOrder] => 0
                )
                [CENTER] => POLICE PSAP
        )
    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [id] => Table2
                    [rowOrder] => 1
                )
                [CENTER] => POLICE PSAP
        )
)
```

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Don't trust `print_r` (or `var_dump`, etc) with SimpleXML objects. They're not "real"/"normal" PHP objects but "magic" wrappers around internal resources, so dumping "the whole object" isn't well defined. So, is there an actual problem accessing the data, or just this `print_r` discrepancy?

Comment: Also, [here's a handy tool for running a test-case like this in multiple PHP versions](https://3v4l.org/ZpsoF) which shows that the behaviour is the same for every version, including HHVM.

Comment: @IMSoP, it seems that I can. But surely this is then a bug in print_r?

Comment: Not exactly - the SimpleXML object doesn't "contain" those items, it just lets you access them in various ways. So the info given is not *wrong* - you can access `->CENTER` on that item, but you can *also* access `[0]->CENTER` and `[1]->CENTER`. In the same way, the `@attributes` is not a real array, it's just a way of forcing `print_r` to show something.

Comment: If you want to put that in the form of an answer, i'll accept it. [EDIT] I just looked at your profile, this is apparently right up your street. I'm going to use your debug lib from now on, thank you. The answer really is the whole "Why" section of your projects readme file and your comment here, above.

Comment: Ah, yes, I must spend some more time on that debug lib... `<guiltyface>`